# Error: SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range at SELECT statement

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, date, where-clause

Here is my  `SELECT` statement with one placeholder `?`:

```
   "select mac_empfangen,count(mac_empfangen) as sum " +
   "FROM mac_erfassung  " +
   "where spender_betaetigt=1 " +
   "and DATE(zeit) >= DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-? days')" +
   "group by  mac_empfangen"
```

I then execute it with

```
db.all(sql,30,(err,results)=>{
  console.log(results)
}
```

But after all comes the error

```
[Error: SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range] {
  errno: 25,
  code: 'SQLITE_RANGE'
}
```

When I run the statement hardcoded (without a placeholder) it works fine.

**Are there any suggestions what the problem might be?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need string concatenation here:

```
and DATE(zeit) >= DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-' || ? || ' days')
```